# Assert that automapper mapping will not throw at runtime because of type discrepancy?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Supposing I have source type

```
class Source 
{
   public string Prop {get; set;}
}
```

target type

```
class Target 
   { 
      public long Prop {get;set;}
   }
```

and I have an AutoMapper mapping from Source to Target.

AssertConfigurationIsValid will work, but the mapping will fail at runtime.

Is there an out-of-the-box way (apart from actually creating [mock] objects of the source and target types and running unit tests on them) to assert that mapping will not throw at runtime due to lack of type conversion?

**UPDATE**

Here's a console app to reproduce the case:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Source, Target>());
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Source
    {
        public string Prop { get; set; }
    }

    public class Target
    {
        public long Prop { get; set; }
    }
```

No exception is thrown until an attempt is made to actually do the mapping...

Comment: The mapping will succeed if the string is indeed a long and fail otherwise. So a conversion does exist.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu yes but what do you mean saying “a string is indeed a long” - it is not, and that’s the problem

Comment: And how could possibly some code that doesn't know all possible values beforehand report that the mapping will throw? You have configuration time and you have runtime. Clearly you cannot guess the runtime value at config time.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu sure, the point however is: suppose someone suddenly changed property type in target. The types are obviously incompatible. The question is: is there a way to check for that beforehand in automapper before the app crashes at runtime ? Maybe some extension to automapper etc?

Comment: Then AssertConfigurationIsValid should throw.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu it doesn't in my example (see update)

Comment: You could use a function to do the mapping if you know the specific variable. I think you can do this using forMember. If not you could use the after map property but you would have to handle the actual mapping first to stop it throwing. This is sssuming you know the actual property name rather than have this happen in all cases

Comment: And I've already explained why. You're missing smth.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu what am I missing? ))

Comment: Probably related to https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2799